# How to trigger alert message for incorrect data uploaded to array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, try-catch

Im new to React and what I'm trying to achieve here is that the csv data uploaded by the user is following the current standard “currency, amount, price, timestamp” If the user is not providing the right csv standard it is going to alert an error.

At the moment I get an error message for whatever data is put in and it's alerting multiple times. What can I do so the alert message is only alerting when the current standard is missing and make this try-catch better?
Thanks in advance.

```
const CSVUpload = (props) => { 

 // process CSV data
 const processData = (dataString) => {
  ...
 };

 const handleFileUpload = async (e) => {
 const file = e.target.files[0];
 const reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = (evt) => {
  ...
 };
 reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

 try {
   const uploadData = [];
   data.forEach((res) => {
     uploadData.push({  
     
       currency: res.currency
         ? res.currency
         : alert('Unable to find currency'),  
       amount: res.amount
         ? res.amount
         : alert('Unable to find amount'),
       price: res.price
         ? res.price
         : alert('Unable to find price'),
       timestamp: res.timestamp
         ? res.timestamp
         : alert('Unable to find timestamp'),
     });
   });
  
   } catch (err) { }

  };

  export default CSVUpload;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const uploadData = [];

try {
  data.forEach(item => {
    if (!item.currency || !item.amount || !item.price || !item.timestamp) {
      throw new Error("You have provided csv file with incorrect format");
    }
    uploadData.push(item);
  });
} catch (err) {
  alert(err.message);
}
```

I also recommend you to look at PapaParse, it has lot of useful api for csv files